# Form action for controller in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm searching the answer but without any luck. Perhaps I asked wrong question. I have a form in my cms page in PS 1.6. Code below:

```
<form method="post" action=""><input name="text1" type="text" /><br /> <input value="Check" onclick="getStatus()" type="button" /></form>
```

In \override\controllers\front\CmsController.php I have getStatus function. Which return "Hello world". Like You see "action" in form is empty. How to create link to this controller which is overrider ?

Kind regards

Comment: You want to set action that call getStatus() function ?

Comment: yes exactly. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this.

In tpl

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="text1" type="text" /><br /> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="getStatus">
<input value="Check"  type="submit" />
</form>
```

In Override controller

```
class CmsController extends CmsControllerCore
{
    public function initContent(){
        parent::initContent();
        if(Tools::getValue('action') && Tools::getValue('action')=='getStatus'){
             // Do your work What you want
             echo  "Hello world";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put: _PS_URI_?controller=cms&id_cms=1

Also can check dispatcher core and add your own rule or create a little module.

If is an override Controller u delete the file cache/class_index.php ?

Comment: I change cms to 4 bcs this is a id of page. Now we have got: action="prestashop.suszek.info?controller=cms&id_cms=4" but still nothing happend.

Comment: have you delete the cache and the class_index.php?  have you try to put your code directly in cmsController without override and it works?